# Maximize the particular subarray sum by rearranging the array elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

How to maximize the particular subarray sum by rearranging the array elements ?

Consider the array like this :

> [5,1,4,6,7]

When we choose a indices[0,2] to get the subarray sum within this range like [5,1,4] we get the sum as 10, but we can maximize this sum if we rearrange array as :

> [5,7,6,1,4]

Now we have maximized the subarray sum for the indices[0,2] as 18.

We can have many queries for the subarray indices for which we have to maximize the sum.

How do I proceed ? Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious fact - your range should contain only the biggest elements of the array.

Therefore, solution: sort the array, calculate the sum of all prefixes of the sorted array. Now if you need to maximize the range of length 3 the answer is the sum of the first 3 numbers (already calculated in preprocessing).

This solution uses O(n log n) in preprocessing and O(1) to answer each query.